# How to Import data from multiple links in excel without vba and macros?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vba

I want to fetch data in excel from this link for around 1000 stocks

   if I use (Data>import from web )function I have to do it separately for each stock. Is there any other method so that symbol(in link) automatically replaced by stock name and get data saperately for each stock.

Comment: Please do your own research.  Google "excel formula import stock quotes".  There are plenty of examples already out there

Answer (score 0):

Please do your own research in the future.  There are many examples out there as to how to get stock quotes.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140726204903-2030824-excel-formula-for-real-time-stock-price

Comment: Thank you sir.. but data fetched by WEBSERVICE("https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=3IINFOTECH&x=NSE&i=300&p=35m&f=l,h") is in simple text form and has multiple numerical values so adding NUMBERVALUE before it giving error.  So how to split this data in different cells and also I want to auto update it every 5 min. I have tried google but didnt find what i actually want.